# How can you change the class of clicked mapped item in a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-state, react-functional-component

I am attempting to change the class of a clicked sorting element ('ascending'/'descending') in a table within a functional React component.
Since I am mapping the table and checking the global state, it is possible for me to see which column to sort and which direction is currently selected using useState(), but how can I change **only** the class of the table item which was clicked (to className `sort-symbol-up` or `sort-symbol-down`)? setState is unfortunately out of the question for functional components.

Currently, it obviously changes the direction of the sort icon for all sorting buttons.

```
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(false);
  const currentDirection = useSelector(state => state.direction);

  const handleClick = src=> {
    setDirection(prevState => !prevState);
    const params = {
      src,
      direction: direction == false ? "desc" : "asc"
    };
    dispatch(sort(params));
  };
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {columns.map((c, id) => (
            <th
              key={`id}`}
            >
              <button               
                onClick={() => handleClick(c.src)}
              >
                {c.label}
                <div
                  className={`sort-symbol-${
                    currentDirection == "asc" ? "down" : "up"
                  }`}
                ></div>
              </button>
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the end, by passing the id to the onClick event. Then dispatched it and stored it in state, to be checked before rendering the correct sort symbol:

```
const [direction, setDirection] = useState(false);
  const currentDirection = useSelector(state => state.direction);
  const selectedColumn = useSelector(state => state.selectedColumn);
  const handleClick = (src, id) => {
    setDirection(prevState => !prevState);
    const params = {
      src,
      direction: direction == false ? "desc" : "asc",
      id
    };
    dispatch(sort(params)); // the id is then dispatched to be stored in state 
  };
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {columns.map((c, id) => (
            <th
              key={`id}`}
            >
              <button      
               //passing the id to the onClick event        
                onClick={() => handleClick(c.src, id)}
              >
                {c.label}
                <div
                  className={`sort-symbol-${
                //checking state for the currently selected column before changing sort symbol
                    selectedColumn === id && currentDirection == "asc" ? "down" : "up" 
                  }`}
              </button>
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
```